# Find different line in 2 UNSORTED files with different size

Tags: linux

I have to files f_hold and f_new. f_new is 2 times bigger than f_hold. Both files are unsorted.
How can I discard lines in f_new which are in f_hold? ex:

f_hold:

```
aaa    
bbb    
ccc    
ddd
eee
```

f_new:

```
ppp
ddd
aaa
ccc
bbb
fff
jjj
nnn
```

what I want:

```
ppp
fff
jjj
nnn
```

So, it is not a simple line by line comparison.
I tried several tips like 'grep -Fxv -f', 'comm' etc... but they are making line by line comparison. Is there a linux command to do that?

Comment: Do you care about preserving the original order?

Comment: No I do not care about the original order.

Comment: Does f_new have lines which are duplicates which you which to retain multiples of?  Say 'xxx' occurs 5 times in f_new and 3 times in f_old.  'yyy' twice in f_new and zero in f_old. How many instances of 'xxx' and 'yyy' need to be in f_new?

Comment: Only one occurance in each file.

Comment: it would be helpful to know the maximum length of the lines, and the nature of the date e.g. IP addresses  genomic, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the example you provided, using grep will work:

```
grep -v -f f_hold f_new
```

-f flag means "read from file"

-v flag is used for invert matching.

UPDATE:

I guess awk can be much faster:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' f_hold f_new
```

Comment: grep -v -f does not work, it produces: ppp aaa ccc bbb fff jjj nnn

Comment: what is your environment? what is the version of grep? do you have empty lines in your files? try removing empty lines. this works on both freeBSD (2.5.1-FreeBSD) and GNU (v2.24) versions of grep.

Comment: You are right, the space after at the end of the words was the problem, it works fine.

Comment: My files are quite big 80.000 lines for file_1 and 1.500.000 lines for file_2. I split file_2 into files of 80.000 lines, but still quite long. Let me know if there is a way to speed up the process.

Comment: you can also use awk, which I believe can be faster. I updated the answer.